# Pegando valor numérico de URL uol

Tags: php

Gostaria de saber como posso usar php para pegar somente o valor numérico desta url de imagem UOL  http://thumb.mais.uol.com.br/15516553-medium.jpg?ver=1 neste caso somente o 15516553 e destacar todo resto sendo que preciso que pegue sempre o valor numérico sempre na mesma posição entre  / e  -medium.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar `regex` para isso, exemplo:

```
$url = 'http://thumb.mais.uol.com.br/15516553-medium.jpg?ver=1';
preg_match("/^.*(uol.com.br\/)(\d+)-*/", $url, $valores);

echo $valores[2]; // seu id ficará na posição [2]
```

**Saída**

> 15516553

### [IdeOne Exemplo](http://ideone.com/tL4Bz3)

### [Análise do RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/sX8iJ4/1)

Comment: Grato pela ajuda